# Updating Status Label C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, function

I have a WinForm C# application, and I am generating a pdf file programmatically and sending it by Email. I am trying to display a status label that shows the status (Generating File, Sending, Sent Successfully or Failed). But it only displays the last status (Sent Successfully).
What should I do to display the status update?

I have tried the below code.

```
try
  {                
      Status_Label.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Status_Label.Text ="Generating PDF fie..."));

      /*
      GENERATING CODE TO CREATE PDF FILE
      */

      Status_Label.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Status_Label.Text = "Sending Email..."));

       /*
      GENERATING CODE for sending the Email
      */

      Status_Label.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Status_Label.Text = "Sent successfully."));


  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {  
       Status_Label.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Status_Label.Text = "Sending failed."));
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked any of the Links under the `Related` section on the right of this page ..this sounds like a good place to start as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152075/multithreading-in-c-sharp-update-labels?rq=1

Comment: Use a `BackgroundWorker`. It seems like you're running the mentioned code from the GUI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You should use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for stuff like this. It runs on a separate thread, but can publish progress to the calling thread (often the UI thread).

Answer (score 1):

That's because the GUI thread is doing all the work and while it is stuck in your method the GUI won't get updated. Doing GUI updates with a command [won't work either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341731/why-wont-control-update-refresh-mid-process). So you'll have to put your PDF generation and e-mail sending into its own thread.
I'd activate a timer in the GUI thread which reads a (synchronized!) queue that is being filled by your new thread. If there's a new element in the queue you fill the label with its contents until the thread terminates, at which point you stop the timer.

Comment: Actually my code is inside a timer, and i am starting the timer. which is a tread by it self i think...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a BackgroundWorker to generate the PDF file and use the ProgressChanged event and ReportProgress function to update your status label.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the tag, your question doesn't mention multithreading.  Are you currently doing all this generation in your UI thread?  (I.e. as a direct result of some registered event like a button click.)  If that is so, the problem is that all of your code executes before the UI updates again.

If this *is* running only in one thread, just change `Status_Label.Text` and then call `Application.DoEvents()`.  This will force the application to deal with any other queued up UI events, and return to your function.

Comment: My code is inside a timer, and i am starting the timer on the END button in the form.